# Google Cloud Datastore emulator export/import not working

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have configured datastore emulator and it is running successfully. But when I export or import entities it is returning error. I am using Windows and below are the commands -

Export:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8081/v1/projects/<project-id>:export -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"output_url_prefix\":\"C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\Data\"}"
```

Returns ->

> {"error":{"code":500,"message":"Failed to export entities.","status":"INTERNAL"}}

Import:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8081/v1/projects/<project-id>:import -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"input_url\":\"C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/Data/file.overall_export_metadata\"}"
```

Returns ->

> {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Failed to parse overall export metadata file","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}

Import error is due to the absence of the exported file.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/errors)

> INVALID_ARGUMENT  Indicates that a request parameter has an invalid
>   value. The message field in the error response provides information as
>   to which value was invalid.   Do not retry without fixing the problem.

Also why are you using \"C:\Users\\Desktop\Data\" as path. I think it should be "C:\Users\\Desktop\Data\".

Answer (score 0):

Executing CURL requests using the datastore emulator on windows can present some difficulties, as a workaround I suggest you use the emulator on the cloud shell in your project, you can following the instructions on this document [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/emulator-export-import